# When the solution of an infinite system of linear algebraic equations exist and is bounded?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

I face an **infinite** system of linear algebraic equations. What conditions must the matrix $\bf A$ and the vector $\bf b$ satisfy for the existence of the *bounded* solution of the linear system
$$
{\bf A} {\bf x} = {\bf b}?
$$

Discussions [Cramer's rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32961/cramers-rule-for-infinite-dimensional-vectors) and [Physics forum](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-know-if-an-infinite-system-of-linear-equations-has-a-solution.600732/) do not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be given in the well-known monograph "Approximate methods of higher analysis" by Kantorovich and Krylov (pp. 26-27).

The infinite system
$$
{\bf A}{\bf x} = {\bf b}
$$
is called

- regular if $$ \sum_{j = 1}^\infty |a_{i j}| < 1, $$
- fully regular if for a positive constant $\theta$, $$ \sum_{j = 1}^\infty |a_{i j}| \leq 1 - \theta < 1. $$
  Here $a_{i j}$ are the elements of the matrix ${\bf A}$.

Denote by
$$
c_i = 1 - \sum_{j = 1}^\infty |a_{i j}|.
$$
Then, the following theorem holds.

**Theorem**. If the infinite system of linear equations
$$
{\bf A}{\bf x} = {\bf b}
$$
is regular, and the inequality
$$
|b_i| \leq K c_i
$$
holds for a constant $K > 0$, then the bounded solution
$$
|x_i| \leq K
$$
to the infinite system exists.

**Remark** If the infinite system is fully regular, and
$$
|b_i| \leq K \theta
$$
holds, then the bounded solution
$$
|x_i| \leq K
$$
to the infinite system exists.

Comment: is the solution unique?

Comment: yes, it is, please, see the reference

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful information!

Comment: sure thing @Yolbarsop

Comment: The answer seems incorrect. For example assume that A=0 is infinite×infinite matrix. In fact, that mentioned reference, discusses about the infinite linear equation of the form Ax=x+b (or x=Ax+b).

Comment: Do you mean incomolete or completely wrong?

Comment: I am now reading the Russian text (I don't have the English copy at hand). It is indeed for x = A x + b, but we can always write A' x = b for A' = A - I (identity matrix). In other words, substitute $a_{ii}$ by $1 - a_{ii}$.